# MongoDB/PyMongo won't $set attribute to document - but sets all other attributes! (bizarre error)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, defaultdict, mongodb-update

I'm trying to write a defaultdict variable to a document in my MongoDB. Everything else sets fine, just not this one attribute, its bizarre! I'm setting a rather large defaultdict called 'domains', which has worked many times before. Check out this terminal output:

So here's my defaultdict:

```
>>> type(domains) 
<type 'collections.defaultdict'>
```

Its pretty big, about 3mb:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(domains)
3146008
```

Here's the document we'll set it to:

```
>>> db.AggregateResults.find_one({'date':'20110409'}).keys()
[u'res', u'date', u'_id']
```

Let's grab that document's ID:

```
>>> myID = db.AggregateResults.find_one({'date':'20110409'})['_id']
>>> myID
ObjectId('50870847f49a00509a000000')
```

Great, let's set the attribute:

```
>>> db.AggregateResults.update({'_id':myID}, {"$set": {'domains':domains}})
>>> db.AggregateResults.find_one({'date':'20110409'}).keys()
[u'res', u'date', u'_id']
```

EH? It didn't save??

Hmmm...does anything save at all?

```
>>> db.AggregateResults.update({'_id':myID}, {"$set": {'myTest':'hello world'}})
>>> db.AggregateResults.find_one({'date':'20110409'}).keys()
[u'myTest', u'res', u'date', u'_id']
```

Okay...so it can save things fine...perhaps its because MongoDB doesn't like defaultdicts? Let's try:

```
>>> myDD = defaultdict(int)
>>> myDD['test'] = 1
>>> myDD
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'test': 1})
>>> db.AggregateResults.update({'_id':myID}, {"$set": {'myDD':myDD}})
>>> db.AggregateResults.find_one({'date':'20110409'}).keys()
[u'myTest', u'res', u'date', u'myDD', u'_id']
```

So it can save defaultdicts fine, just not this one??

So strange! Any ideas why??

EDIT with safe=True:

```
>>> db.AggregateResults.update({'_id':myID}, {"$set": {'domains':domains}}, safe=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.1.1_-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 405, in update
    _check_keys, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.1.1_-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 796, in _send_message
    return self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.1.1_-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 746, in __check_response_to_last_error
    raise OperationFailure(error["err"], error["code"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not okForStorage
```

[This GoogleGroup discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/9qUaTWHkojM) says that could be due to having fullstops in the keys, but:

```
>>> [x for x in domains.keys() if '.' in x]
[]
```

Comment: I tried running through this code (or process, I didn't copy/paste your code to give it a close testing) and it all worked for me, I am not sure what happened during your attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! Found it!

Not only can keys in MongoDB not have '.', they also cannot have '$' in them.

See:

```
>>>[x for x in domains.keys() if '$' in x]
['$some_key_']
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to save too large of a document.  MongoDB imposes a 16MB maximum size on all of its documents.

Try running the update command with the parameter `safe=True`.  This will run in safe mode, which will instruct the database to send back the result of the attempted insert.

Comment: I did sys.getsizeof and its just over 3mb so should be OK. However, There is an error when using safe=True, but its not very specific - see edit above :)